# I need some Makefile wizardry explained

Tags: c++, makefile

So I was following one of the Makefile by example tutorials (cause I'm fairly fresh) and thats how I ended up here.

```
files = src/main.cpp src/compiler.cpp

all: $(files)

%.cpp:
        echo $@
```

And this for some reason produces this

```
echo src/compiler.cpp
src/compiler.cpp
echo all.cpp
all.cpp
g++    -c -o all.o all.cpp
cc1plus: fatal error: all.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: all.o] Error 1
```

I don't see any refrences to g++ at all and for some reason it's getting called. The idea here was to use it to compile all my stuff from /src to .o files in /obj then produce a binary. Any ideas on how to do that or explanations on how to not call g++ without even referencing it in the makefile is highly appreciated.

Comment: Huh. I don't understand where the `all.cpp` is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

It's being called because you have created a target `all`, and you haven't given make any recipe to build that target.  So, make looks through its built-in rules and it sees that it knows how to build a program `x` given a prerequisite `x.cpp`.  Well, make knows how to build a `all.cpp`, because you provided a rule that tells it how to build any `.cpp` file.

So first it runs the rule to build `all.cpp`, then it runs its built-in rule to build a target `all` from that `all.cpp` (which doesn't exist because your rule that told make how to build `%.cpp` doesn't actually create that target).

If you don't actually want to build a target `all`, then you should declare it to be a phony target:

```
.PHONY: all
```

Comment: But then nothing will happen when `Make` is run. I guess it'll list any `.cpp` files that you've declared are necessary in `files` but don't actually exist?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why would nothing happen when make is run?

Comment: Because if `src/main.cpp` and `src/compiler.cpp` already exist, which seems likely, then no action is taken in the recipe for `all`.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with whether `all` is phony or not.  If those files already exist then they won't be created (obviously) and nothing will be done regardless of whether `all` is phony.  But we can see from the question that they _don't_ exist, because the rule to create them was run.  And since the makefile doesn't create them (the rule just echos the name without creating the file) they will continue to not exist.

Comment: It seems clear that this is just a toy makefile that doesn't actually do anything useful, and is just trying to experiment with some make concepts, so we shouldn't expect it to make sense :)